# Sencha 2.x MVC: Get element by id

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, mobile, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I just started using Sencha framework 2.x. This is my app:

app/app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  enabled: true
});
Ext.application({
  name: 'App',
  controllers: ['Generators'],
  models: [],
  stores: [],
  views: ['Main', 'Generator'],
  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('App.view.Main');
  }
});
```

app/view/Main.js

```
Ext.define('App.view.Main', {
  extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
  requires: [
    'App.view.Generator'
  ],

  config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
      {
        xtype: 'generatorview'
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

app/view/Generator.js

```
Ext.define('App.view.Generator', {
  extend: 'Ext.Container',
  xtype: 'generatorview',
  id: 'generator',
  config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [
      {
        xtype: 'panel',
        html: 'My message: <a id="xxxSet">Set</a> :: <span id="xxxMsg">...</span>',
        flex: 1
      },
      {
        dock: 'bottom',
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: []
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

app/controller/Generator.js

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Generators', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
  config: {
    refs: {}
  },
  init: function() {
    this.control({
      '#xxxSet': { // QUESTION1
        tap: 'setMyMessage'
      }
    });
  },

  setMyMessage: function() {
    '#xxxMsg'.html('Set this message'); // QUESTION2
  }
});
```

As you can see I placed questions in the last part (controller).

- QUESTION1: How can I set a tap function to the element (#xxxSet)
  defined in the view as HTML content.
- QUESTION2: How can I set a
  message the the element (#xxxMsg) defined in the view as HTML
  content.

xxxSet = id of a button

xxxMsg = id of a message holder

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Ext#get](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext-method-get) (which accepts a string which is the `id`) which will return a instance of [Ext.dom.Element](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element). With that, you can use the [on](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-on) method to add listeners (much like `control`) and then the [setHtml](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-setHtml) method to update the contents.

```
init: function() {
    Ext.get('xxxSet').on({
        tap: 'setMyMessage',
        scope: this
    });
},

setMyMessage: function() {
    Ext.get('xxxMsg).setHtml('Hello');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `itemId`, you can not access it with `Ext.get()`. You can try `Ext.ComponentQuery.query()` instead of that.

```
init: function() {
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#xxxSet').on({
    tap: 'setMyMessage',
    scope: this
  });
},

setMyMessage: function() {
 Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#xxxMsg).setHtml('Hello');
}
```