# Get element by ID returning null for Sencha Controller

Tags: javascript, controller, sencha-touch-2, document, getelementbyid

Here is the controller I want to get

```
  Ext.define('GS.controller.PickStorageController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
  id: 'pickStorageControl',
```

In the launch function I made it print its id

```
  launch: function() 
  {
    console.log(this.id);
  },
```

Here is the output: pickStorageControl

In my code, (after all of the launch functions for  controllers are done) I have this:   `document.getElementById('pickStorageControl');`  Which is apparently null.

How do I fix this??

Before you say that I should be using refs and controls, I need it to work this particular way for my plans to be executed later...

Comment: At your website, right click on the page and view the source. Ctrl+f to search the document and look for "pickStorageControl". Is there an element that has the exact id "pickStorageControl" or is there text surrounding it in some way?

Comment: @ianpgal Unfortunately, because I used the sencha build tools, I can't find the element that way.

Comment: ahh I see, I never heard of Sencha nor did I look it up - I just expected it produced HTML you could look through in a browser. But as I looked into it, could you give the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481597/sencha-2-x-mvc-get-element-by-id a try?

Comment: does it work with views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for get object of controller use this code

```
GS.app.getcontroller('PickStorageController');
```

It will give you controllers object

Comment: I wanted to use the document because I need to get the Controller object using an external script running on a window opened by my app.  In the external script, I can access the app window using 'window.opener', so I tried doing this 'window.opener.GS.app.getController('PickStorageController').dance();' in my external script, and it works!! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The controller will not have an id, only DOM elements will. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you only use getElementById for DOM elements.

Comment: Is there some way to insert an object with an id into the document and then use this method to retrieve it?  I am trying to do so now with little success.

Comment: why do you have to try to put them in your DOM while Sencha core team developers are trying each day to reduce its size? Very bad practice if your do

Comment: Because I want to use an external script to access the controller. I have the document for my main app (window.opener.document), and I need to call a method in my pickStorageController to signal that the external script is running.